# How to exclude a referenced assembly from Dotfuscator CE (VS 2019)?

Tags: android, xamarin, dotfuscator

After removing `library` option (to get better obfuscation) in the dotfuscator config file, the app is crashing when using a referenced third party assembly.

As explained in Dotfuscator documentation, I exclude this assembly using in the `<renaming>` section of the config file :

```
<excludelist>
      <assembly>
        <file dir="path_to_assembly" name="assembly_name"/>
      </assembly>
</excludelist>
```

First, it builds correctly even if "path_to_assembly" contains an error... So it seems those lines in the config file are not analyzed by Dotfuscator. Moreother, in the generated `Renaming.xml`, we can see that fields, functions, etc... of the assembly have been renamed.

I tried to exclude the assembly using the GUI, but "Check below to exclude specific items" is blank.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the Dotfuscator team and was wondering if you could share a little more information. I'm assuming you're using the same Dotfuscator version as mentioned in [Xamarin.Android : Release build ok with R8 or dotfuscator but not both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045837/xamarin-android-release-build-ok-with-r8-or-dotfuscator-but-not-both). I'm having some trouble recreating your issue and was wondering what third party assembly you're referencing. In addition, I was hoping you could post your Dotfuscator config file.